# Adding to list with foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am currently trying to add objects(students). I am creating in a foreach loop to an object list made up of students, each list object ends up referencing to the same location and therefore the information on each list object is the same as the last student object created when the loop ends. The only information I have been able to find for adding an object to a list using a foreach loop states to create a new instance of the object which I thought I was doing with the Student stud = new Student line.

I have also tried using the default constructor and using properties instead of arguments, then adding the student to the list however I receive the same result.

Any help in adding objects to an object list with a foreach loop would be greatly appreciated.

foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataRow datrow in dt.Rows)
{
    Student stud = new Student(
        datrow["ID"].ToString(),
        datrow["fName"].ToString(),
        datrow["lName"].ToString(),
        datrow["GPA"].ToString(),
        datrow["Graduate"].ToString()
    );
    studentList.Add(stud);
}
```

My Student Constructor:

```
public Student(
    string studentID,
    string fName,
    string lName,
    string studentGPA,
    string graduate)
{
    iD = studentID;
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    gPA = studentGPA;
    grad = graduate;
}
```

statement used to fill dt

```
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataAdapter dc = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                dc.Fill(ds, "ID");
                dt = ds.Tables["ID"];
                const char DELIM = ',';
                foreach (DataRow datrow in dt.Rows)
```

"this" information that each object refers to and is re-written for every new object

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: whats wrong with the results? My screen is to small for me to make heads or tails of the picture.

Comment: This code looks correct.  How have you determined that the problem is here and not somewhere else?

Comment: Also, in the first screen shot, how can values for `this` already be populated when you're paused on the *first line* of the constructor?  That seems strange.

Comment: Where did `Courses` come from in your images?

Comment: @David The OP probably paused in the middle of the foreach, not at the beginning.

Comment: Did you check that the rows do not all contain same information? One way to determine if the objects in the list are really all the same or just have same values is to right click and select "generate object id". If they all the same object, they should all get the same id

Comment: @Hank: The `foreach` isn't relevant to that first screen shot.  He's pausing in the constructor and showing the values of the object being constructed.

Comment: Max, please include the statement or query that is used to fill the `dt` object (e.g. Linq or SQL). If all objects contain the same data then probably the rows do too.

Comment: Please check if your datatable is poplulated correctly each iteration does in fact produce a different result.

Comment: @David It could be showing the values of the previously constructed object.

Comment: Why does your Student constructor fill a property `grad` but the screenshot uses `Gradate`? Some for most other properties. The code in the question does not seem to match the actual code that was executed before creating the screen shot.

Comment: @PeterB: I suspect the constructor is setting private values while the debugging is showing public properties which we *assume* to be simple pass-throughs to those private members.  But they might not be.  In any event, you're correct in that the code in the question doesn't produce the problem being described.  So there's really nothing anybody here can do to help.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback, sorry for any mistakes (first time posting)

Comment: Here is the data table, I will include the statement used to fill dt but it is working properly http://i.imgur.com/dcTx7d8.png

Comment: Could you also add the fields and properties of the Student class? Maybe some error in there making them all reference the same values.

Comment: Hi my suggestion is just try like this,                                                  foreach (DataRow datrow in dt.Rows)
{
    Student stud = new Student(
        datrow["ID"].ToString(),
        datrow["fName"].ToString(),
        datrow["lName"].ToString(),
        datrow["GPA"].ToString(),
        datrow["Graduate"].ToString()
    );
    studentList.Add(stud);
}

Comment: @PeterB grad is a private variable i set so the property can grab it.

Comment: Something tells me that the private variables are `static`. Note that `Static Members` hasn't been expanded, so we can't know for certain; but I'd be willing to bet that is how the properties are populated already whilst in the constructor. What is the full definition of your `Student` class? That would also explain why all instances of the class have the same values

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 That was it! Thank you so much I have spent at least a day in research for this. I know it's a silly mistake I should have known of but I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. Apologies for not including that information in the beginning. Thank you to everyone else as well, I'll try to include more information in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your private variables are most likely static. This would explain why the variables already have a value in the constructor (which they wouldn't for normal instance variables). The static values are being returned by your properties (which explains how they have values already as well). Change your variables to instance (not `static`)

Comment: Nice crystal ball :o)

Answer (score 2):

Hi my suggestion is just try by declaring class variable outside  like this, see whether its works

```
Student stud;

    foreach (DataRow datrow in dt.Rows)
    {
            stud = new Student(
            datrow["ID"].ToString(),
            datrow["fName"].ToString(),
            datrow["lName"].ToString(),
            datrow["GPA"].ToString(),
            datrow["Graduate"].ToString()
        );
        studentList.Add(stud);
    }
```

please let me know your suggestions.

thanks
karthik